# Android HttpClient issue setting Content-Length

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, androidhttpclient

I tried to create a post with the following...

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONN_DIRECTIVE, HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE);
String length = String.valueOf(httppost.getEntity().getContentLength());
httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN, length); //If commented out it works
```

but when I try to run the request I get the following error...

> 10-11 22:05:02.940: W/System.err(4203): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

I am guessing this is because the content length is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache HttpClient (even its fork shipped with Android) always calculates content length based on the properties of the enclosed HTTP entity. One does not need (and should not) set `Content-Length` and `Transfer-Encoding` headers manually.

Comment: Ok thanks guess that means there is another reason my post request isn't working. Is this documented somewhere? That may help future searchers.

Comment: @oleg +1 My app was crashing when I was setting this in header of httpPost. Can you please lead me to such do's & dont's of HTTPclient, java?

Comment: @EvolGate There is no compiled list do's and dont's, though, I guess it would be a great contribution to the project. Most of such details can however be found in the tutorial http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/index.html